# Por qué al seleccionar un combobox múltiple no me guarda todo lo seleccionado?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Buenas tardes, estoy haciendo un formulario de emergencias y necesito que me guarde mas de 1 campo seleccionado, pero al momento de seleccionar mas de 2 solo me guarda el ultimo seleccionado [image: aqui esta la interfaz de personal, al final solo me guarda la ultima seleccionada que es conagua]

De cada combo la información sale de una tabla de base de datos.

Aqui es donde inserto todo a la base de datos

```
    <?php
    include('conexion.php');
    $id_id = $_POST['id-prod'];
    $proceso = $_POST['pro'];
       $clasi = $_POST['clasi'];
     $tipo = $_POST['tipo'];
      $desc_emergencia = $_POST['desc_emergencia'];
    $personal = $_POST['personal'];
    $herra = $_POST['herra'];
    $vehi = $_POST['vehi'];
    $name = $_POST['namess'];
    $nombre_reportante = $_POST['nombre_reportante'];
    $telefono_reportante = $_POST['telefono_reportante'];
    $ubicacion = $_POST['ubicacion'];
    $nivel_emergencia = $_POST['nivel_emergencia'];
    $fecha = date('Y/m/d');
    $hora= date("h:i:s");

    //VERIFICAMOS EL PROCESO

    switch($proceso){
    case 'Registro':
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO reporte (id_clasificacion, nombre, 
    desc_emergencia, personal,nombrepersonal, herramientas, vehiculos, 
    nombre_reportante, telefono_reportante, ubicacion, nivel_emergencia, 
    fecha_reporte,hora)VALUES
 ('$clasi','$tipo','$desc_emergencia','$personal','$name','$herra','$vehi','$nombre_reportante','$telefono_reportante','$ubicacion', '$nivel_emergencia' ,'$fecha', '$hora')");

    break;
```

este es donde hago el select que se muestra la pantalla

```
echo 'Personal <select required="required" MULTIPLE  name="personal[]"   
onChange="getNombrePersonal(this.value) ;" >';

$query = "SELECT id_personal, nombre_personal FROM personal WHERE 
id_clasificacion ORDER BY nombre_personal";

if($resultado=$mysqli->query($query))
{
    while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['nombre_personal']; ?>"><?php echo 
$row['nombre_personal']; ?></option>

    <?php
    }
 }
 echo '</select>';
?>
```

muchas gracias

Comment: El código que compartes usa la extensión `mysql_*` que se considera obsoleta y no debería usarse. Además, tiene problemas graves de seguridad y es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar `mysqli_*` o `PDO` en su lugar.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizas un select múltiple el resultado que envía es un array con las opciones seleccionadas que hay que recorrer.

Un ejemplo de cómo ver las opciones seleccionadas:

```
foreach($_POST["personal"] as $seleccionado) {
 echo $seleccionado;
}
```

Lo que ya no sé es si quieres guardarlo en base de datos como un único campo, en cuyo caso puedes hacer un implode del array `$_POST["personal"]`, o como distintos campos.

Answer (score 0):

Quiero indicar algunas cosas.

1. No es necesario llamar a los select múltiples de esta manera: `nombre []`, no sé por qué esta práctica se ha extendido en la red. En el ejemplo, vamos a darle el id: `personal` a nuestro `select`
2. El pasarle el valor cada vez que el `select` cambie a una función de Javascript no sirve de nada, a no ser que lo vayas almacenando en una variable global, lo cual no parece ser una buena idea. Mejor, llamaremos a la función `onclick` y recorreremos el `select` por su `id`, para verificar su estado al momento de ocurrir ese evento, guardando en un arreglo todos los valores seleccionados. Verás que el `console.log` del código imprimirá el arreglo con todos los valores que haya seleccionados cada vez que hagas clic en el `select`. Esta es una manera de tener cada vez los valores precisos que están seleccionados.
3. A partir de ahí, sacar los valores seleccionados, es pan comido. En el ejemplo se almacenan los valores del texto con: `seleccionados.push(x.options[i].text);`, pero puedes almacenar también los datos de la etiqueta `value` con: `seleccionados.push(x.options[i].value);`, o puedes almacenar ambos, eso dependerá del uso que quieras darle.

**Nota:** Este es código Javascript puro, sin intervención de librerías externas.

```js
function getNombrePersonal()
{
var seleccionados = [];

var x=document.getElementById("personal");
for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) 
{
   if(x.options[i].selected ==true)
   {
   //seleccionados.push(x.options[i].value);
     seleccionados.push(x.options[i].text);

   }
}
console.log(seleccionados);
}
```

```html
    <select multiple id="personal" onclick="getNombrePersonal() ;">
      <option value="1">Valor 1</option> 
      <option value="2">Valor 2</option>
      <option value="3">Valor 3</option>
      <option value="4">Valor 4</option>
      <option value="5">Valor 5</option>
      <option value="6">Valor 6</option>
      <option value="7">Valor 7</option>

    </select>
```

---

#### Nota sobre la seguridad

Tus consultas SQL son vulnerables a la **[Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/29967)**. Los estándares modernos de programación exigen que bajo ningún concepto de construyan consultas de esta manera:

`INSERT INTO reporte (id_clasificacion, nombre, ...) VALUES
 ('$clasi','$tipo',...)`

sino que la práctica recomendada es el uso de [**consultas preparadas**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para evitar el uso de código dañino por usuarios mal intencionados.